# Headers on Tablix [SSRS] not showing up on additional pages besides first [Pagination]

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, pagination, rdl

I have a relatively simple RDL.

It has a graph on the first page.
And then a tablix that is paginated that shows 4 columns of data.
With a blue header that only shows up on the very first page.

What I Have done so far:

- On the static row group where the header row is I have set:

  - **KeepWithGroup** to After
  - **RepeatOnNewPage** to True
- On the Tablix Properties itself I have enabled:

  - Repeat header rows on each page
  - Repeat header columns on each page

The xml for the RDL looks as it should.

By all counts from what I can gather from the online walk-thrus it should work, but it simply does not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you specify page breaks rather than just letting SSRS decide when to do a page break?

Comment: It still does not work even after doing so. :/

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone into the Tablix Group Properties' **Advanced Mode**?
In the **Grouping** for the Tablix, click on the drop down arrow and click on **Advanced Mode**.

Click on the **Static** items and the related cell will be highlighted. Change the **RepearOnNewPage** property (in the Properties window) to **True** and **KeepWithGroup** to **After**.

Here's a better explanation with plenty of pics:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3447/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-repeating-headers-on-pages/

Comment: Yup. if you notice my very first post - I mentioned that I did both of those things :)

Comment: Ah - I wasn't sure if you were talking about the advanced mode settings or the general group properties.
Does your tablix have a **column** group that isn't set to repeat? 
If nothing else, it might be quicker to create a new tablix from scratch rather than trying to find the issue.